# Find exact attribute value match

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am comparing a section of two xml files;

Source file -

```
<parent>
<tag attrib1="val1">
...
</parent>
```

Target file -

```
<parent>
<tag attrib1="val1" attrib2="val2">
...
</parent>
```

python v2.7; Elementree v1.3

When I use targetroot.find(".//parent[@attrib1='val1']"), it returns me the element with 2 attributes; but I want an eaxct match, so in this case case it should not return me anything becuase target does not have an element with **only 1 attribute** (with value 'val1')

What should I do to get an exact match?

Answer (score 0):

Use xpath:
targetroot.xpath(".//parent/tag[@attrib1='val1' and count(@*) = 1]")

Comment: The `xpath()` method is available in lxml. It does not work with ElementTree.